# Your current user or role does not have access to Kubernetes objects on this EKS cluster - EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create an EKS Cluster with Managed Node Group. I'm being thrown this error when the Managed node group gets created. **Your current user or role does not have access to Kubernetes objects on this EKS cluster. This may be due to the current user or role not having Kubernetes RBAC permissions to describe cluster resources or not having an entry in the cluster’s auth config map.**. I have setup all the necessary IAM roles and policies needed for the EKS Cluster to run. Any help will be appreciated.

EKS Version: 1.18

Comment: Which docs you followed?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html#policy_example3

Comment: Have you attached your policy to K8s user or group in the aws-auth configmap?  
Can you update your question with your config so that we can have more insight what is going in (aws-auth cm, k8s rbac etc)

Comment: Can you also go thru [those troubleshooting steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting_iam.html#security-iam-troubleshoot-cannot-view-nodes-or-workloads) and confirm that all are correct for you config ?

Comment: aws-auth-file: https://dpaste.org/QoMd (Similar to the left one)
 RBAC Policy : https://dpaste.org/jJ8d

Comment: check region..in my case i have create cluster in one region and looked into another region

Comment: @TsNarayanan have you found a solution to this? If yes can you post here.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate K8S question that belongs to SO (review the other near 40K questions that we have here) - and specifically - it deals with Users auth and RBAC. Probably the user that is trying to view the resources is not the user that created the cluster and should be added to the aws-auth ConfigMap within Kubernetes.